# Multiple connections on random high port numbers

Tags: networking, hacking

Having some issues with my laptop slowing down Ubuntu 20.04.
Checking netstat shows multiple Established keepalive connections on random high ports, originating from port 443 on foreign computer.
CPU usage is high but cant find whats using it.
I have just uninstalled and reinstalled chrome which has helped.
Are these connections normal? Not an IT person just seems a little odd.

```
    Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Timer
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:53884      104.18.130.236:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (20.72/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:53266      104.18.40.222:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (4.34/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:55602      151.101.65.181:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (35.06/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:45592      23.55.3.87:443          ESTABLISHED keepalive (0.24/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:33384      172.217.24.34:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (24.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:50656      142.250.4.188:5228      ESTABLISHED keepalive (37.10/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:55890      142.250.66.163:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (20.72/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:51840      142.251.143.163:443     ESTABLISHED keepalive (2.29/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:38292      130.211.33.34:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (2.29/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:34296      23.55.3.87:443          ESTABLISHED keepalive (0.24/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:49454      142.251.221.66:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (4.34/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:60130      207.65.33.78:443        ESTABLISHED keepalive (30.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:47348      18.67.111.87:443        ESTABLISHED keepalive (41.20/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41100      151.101.65.181:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (33.01/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:46776      172.217.24.33:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (6.39/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:59592      172.217.24.42:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (4.34/0/6)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:42124      151.101.65.108:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (30.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:33774      52.223.2.229:443        ESTABLISHED keepalive (24.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41768      142.251.221.78:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (0.24/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41594      172.217.24.42:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (20.72/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:54544      172.217.24.40:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (16.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:58966      198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (22.77/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:45588      23.55.3.87:443          ESTABLISHED keepalive (0.24/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:39586      151.101.65.181:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (35.06/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:55776      172.64.150.156:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (18.67/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:56604      18.239.199.109:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (30.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:45982      146.75.92.193:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (16.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41662      104.18.130.236:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (24.81/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41732      13.224.181.123:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (28.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:34918      172.217.24.34:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (18.67/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:35414      172.217.24.42:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (12.52/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:34312      23.55.3.87:443          ESTABLISHED keepalive (2.28/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:35358      216.239.38.178:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (20.72/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:59152      172.217.24.34:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (43.24/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:41328      204.79.197.204:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (4.33/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:52160      216.239.32.116:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (30.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:46762      172.217.24.33:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (6.38/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.12:47002      104.18.32.137:443       ESTABLISHED keepalive (20.71/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 192.168.1.12:68         192.168.1.1:67          ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58776           0.0.0.0:*                           off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::1900                 :::*                                off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::56808                :::*                                off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                off (0.00/0/0)
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           off (0.00/0/0)
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/75841/what-is-1e100-net-and-why-do-i-have-tcp-ports-open-to-it). All those IP addresses belong to Google, so it's some Chrome "feature".

Comment: I think that the connections are origination FROM your computer, connecting TO those IP-addresses ...

Answer (score 0):

All these connetions are outgoing from your PC to external web servers. Try to find which local process originates the connections. I suppose it can be a web browser.

```
sudo netstat -lntp
```

The command above will display process numbers in last column.

Here is an output example, the process number from last column is 6895 in all lines:

```
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.111:44248        34.149.100.209:443      ESTABLISHED     6895/firefox-trunk  
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.111:53812        34.107.243.93:443       ESTABLISHED     6895/firefox-trunk  
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.111:33646        198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED     6895/firefox-trunk
```

Details about process:

```
ps -ef | grep 6895
```

Find these processes and stop or kill them. Explore circumstances why and when these processes are started.

You can discover the real cause of high CPU load by using the `top` command.

```
sudo top
```

Look for processes with a high value in the `% CPU` column.